# Referencing Elements of Class Arrays using C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, object

I am trying to switch the elements of a class array using pointers. It is not outputting what I want. I tried using pointers in the function, but it's not allowed. It's also not allowed to call the function onto the class object without using a pointer, since I declared the class object using a double pointer. I am not using this method simply to solve a small problem, but just to practice using this method for more difficult problems.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class thing{
public:
    int index;
    int value;
    thing();
private: int number;

};
thing::thing()
{
    number = 0;
}
void arrange(thing array[]){
    for(int i=0; i<19; ++i){
        if(array[i].value<array[i+1].value){
            swap(array[i], array[i+1]);
            arrange(array);
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    thing** things = new thing*[20];
    for (int i=0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        things[i] = new thing();  // default constructor
        things[i]->index = i;
        things[i]->value=rand() % 100;
    }
    cout << "The random array is: " << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<20;++i){
        cout << things[i]->value << endl;
    }
    arrange(*things);
    cout << "The arranged array is: " << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cout << things[i]->value << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you expect your program to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `arrange(*things)`, you're just passing the first element of `things` to the function, not the array. It should be `array(things)`. Then the `arrange` function should be written to use pointers:

```
void arrange(thing* array[]){
    for(int i=0; i<19; ++i){
        if(array[i]->value<array[i+1]->value){
            swap(array[i], array[i+1]);
            arrange(array);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you create an array of pointers to `thing`:

```
thing** things = new thing*[20];
```

Here you dereference it and get a pointer to `thing` which is stored at `thing[0]`:

```
arrange(*things);
```

But this function declaration

```
void arrange(thing array[])
```

treats this pointer as an array of `thing`, so that `*things` points to it first element, which is absolutely not what it really is.

---

You should change your `arrange()` function to use correct type:

```
void arrange(thing* array[]){
    for(int i=0; i<19; ++i){
        if(array[i]->value<array[i+1]->value){
            swap(array[i], array[i+1]);
            arrange(array);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it as:

```
arrange(things);
```

---

Regarding using vectors, you don't need to use any pointers at all.

```
std::vector<thing> things(20);
for (int i=0; i < things.size(); ++i)
{
    things[i].index = i;
    things[i].value=rand() % 100;
}

arrange(things);


void arrange(std::vector<thing>& array){
    for(int i=0; i + 1 < things.size(); ++i){
        if(array[i].value<array[i+1].value){
            swap(array[i], array[i+1]);
            arrange(array);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. How would I go about doing the same thing with vectors instead of arrays? I've replaced void arrange(thing* array[]) with void arrange(vector<thing>* array) and now it's not allowed to use -> instead asking to use . (dot) notation, then gives an error. I created a new vector in the form of vector<thing>** things = new thing*[20] which it is accepting.